# How to Monitor Informatica Jobs and send mail about the Job Status using Python?

Tags: python

I have been given task to monitor the informatica jobs about its status and send mail to the recipients automatically if jobs get abandoned or takes long time to process. All this should be done using python Scripts. Can you kindly advise how to do that?

Unfortunately there are no more info like where the status are getting updated in the file and its format. I wonder is there any specific module in Python to do all this stuffs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well split the problem up and google it.
First you want to parse a website -> `splinter`.
Then you probably want to store data -> `pickle`.
Finally to send an email try `smtplib`.
To answer your question: Sure you can create these scripts. Its just a very general question so I hope you dont mind the general answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have already googled but unsuccessful. I am completely noob in informatica. To be precise, The reqiuirement is to login the informatica workflow manager and monitoring the running jobs. I also assume that this has to be done in AWS which I don't have knowledge on... Is AWS website can be scraped? Is informatica workflow manager runs as website application??

Comment: Well as far as I see it, it is a website. I can build that, but thats like a propper project and goes a little beyond this comment section. Try to split it into parts and go step by step.